# How to avoid unchecking parent node when child node is unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a java script where all child nodes are checked when parent node is checked but my problem is when I'm unchecking child node, parent node is also unchecked.I dont want my parent node to uncheck when child node is unchecked.
My script is

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function chkitemscript() {
            $("[id*=TreeView1] input[type=checkbox]").bind("click", function () {
                var table = $(this).closest("table");
                if (table.next().length > 0 && table.next()[0].tagName == "DIV") {
                    //Is Parent CheckBox
                    var childDiv = table.next();
                    var isChecked = $(this).is(":checked");
                    $("input[type=checkbox]", childDiv).each(function () {
                        if (isChecked) {
                            $(this).attr("checked", "checked");
                        } else {
                            $(this).removeAttr("checked");
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    //Is Child CheckBox
                    var parentDIV = $(this).closest("DIV");
                    if ($("input[type=checkbox]", parentDIV).length == $("input[type=checkbox]:checked", parentDIV).length) {
                        $("input[type=checkbox]", parentDIV.prev()).attr("checked", "checked");
                    } else {
                        $("input[type=checkbox]", parentDIV.prev()).removeAttr("checked");
                    }
                }
            });
        })

    </script>
```

Comment: Joining HTML markup would have been great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   else {
                    //Is Child CheckBox
                    var parentDIV = $(this).closest("DIV");
                    if ($("input[type=checkbox]", parentDIV).length == $("input[type=checkbox]:checked", parentDIV).length) {
                        $("input[type=checkbox]", parentDIV.prev()).attr("checked", "checked");
                    } else {
                        $("input[type=checkbox]", parentDIV.prev()).removeAttr("checked");
                    }
                }
```

Please remove the above else part this may work